# App location for Snip & Sketch

Tags: windows-10

I want to make my own hot key for Window's 10 Snip & Sketch. I have it installed on my OS and I can run it from the search menu. However, I can not find the app location of it. Anyone know where it lives?

Comment: `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`. But 1) it is hidden 2) users have no rights to browse it. To access you must change owner and set proper permissions for this folder. But it may cause some problems... if you'll do it nevertheless - save original permissions before and restore owner after.

Answer (score 5):

The Windows 10 Snip & Sketch App is a Microsoft Store (UWP) App, so it does not have a traditional ".exe" file or location that can be accessed to create a hotkey.

If you want to create a Hotkey to a UWP App (eg. Snip & Sketch), the easiest way is:

1. Type `Shell:Appsfolder` in file explorer's address bar or from the Run dialogue (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

This will open the "virtual" start menu apps folder for us to work with.

2. Locate the App (eg. Snip & Sketch), right click and select "Create shortcut." Allow the shortcut to be placed on Desktop.
3. Right click on shortcut, enter properties and customize shortcut key.

Comment: Is it possible to pin Snip & Sketch to the Windows 10 start menu? It sounds like no.

Comment: You should be able to pin it like any App. By default it's in the Start Menu All Apps List, so you should be able to just right-click on the icon to pin to the Start Menu Tiles.

Comment: Yes, that worked. For some reason it took a long time to open up the Pin to Start option when I right clicked, like 30 s, but then it did. Thanks!