# Pinned shortcut to Snip & Sketch on start menu does not respond to first letter key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I am running the horrid Windows 10 operating system.

I used the information from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1479215/app-location-for-snip-sketch?newreg=1f4a2302873c4800aa2669f838cfdc32) to create a shortcut to the Snip & Sketch UWP thingy and pinned it to my Start Menu. I use the classic Windows XP Start Menu and when I open it I can press a key on my keyboard and it will jump to the first entry whose name begins with said key.

For some reason the Snip & Sketch entry, however, is being totally ignored for some reason.

How can I fix that so that I can select the entry with a key press?

Comment: How have you pinned it to the Start Menu?

Comment: @John, try rereading the question. The words "classic Windows XP Start Menu" are easy to miss but might be a clue to "works on my machine" not being especially helpful. Or smart.

Comment: @harrymc, created the shortcut, opened the Start Menu, drag and dropped it there. Basically the shortcut resides in "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu".

Comment: @John, searching in the search box is not "Windows 10 methodology" which you would know if you could: A - read, B - understand word definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your Start replacement, but with mine it worked this way:

Right-click the shortcut on the desktop and select "Pin to Start menu".

This is instead of dropping it on Start.

If you do not want to pin the shortcut to the Start menu,
I believe that the problem comes from the fact that Snip & Sketch is a
UWP app, which Classic Windows XP Start Menu apparently does not support.

You could move to another Start menu replacement that does support UWP,
for example
[Open Shell Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu).